# Call AS400 SP and return recordset into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a SP on an IBM AS400 box that I need to call and return the recordset into a SQL Server 2012 table.  How do I perform this is the world of SQL Server?

I call the IBM SP like this from SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @PC CHAR(20)
DECLARE @TIME CHAR(6)
DECLARE @WHLO CHAR(3)
DECLARE @BODT1 CHAR(8)
DECLARE @BODT2 CHAR(8)
DECLARE @SEAS CHAR(2)

SET @PC='XXXXXXXX'
SET @TIME ='142000'
SET @WHLO='100'
SET @BODT1='20150319'
SET @BODT2='00000000'
SET @SEAS='SS'

EXEC ('CALL XXXX.SL400SP(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ', 
      @PC, @TIME, @WHLO, @BODT1, @BODT2, @SEAS OUTPUT) 
      AT XXXXXXXXX
```

My question is though, how do I get the resultset from the above into a SQL Server temporary table?  Is it just a case of looping through the recordset and inserting the values?  What about closing the connections?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you do a `select * from (exec....)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the results into a temp table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (id INT, ... [other columns defined here])

INSERT #TEMP 
EXEC ('CALL XXXX.SL400SP(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ', 
      @PC, @TIME, @WHLO, @BODT1, @BODT2, @SEAS OUTPUT) 
      AT XXXXXXXXX)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP

DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

This will take the results of the stored procedure and `INSERT` them into the temp table.

Comment: Ok thanks.  Do I need to close the IBM stored procedure?  I recall you have to in VBA but not sure about SQL.